# Travelling restrictions from Budapest, Hungary to Lisbon, Portugal

Tags: schengen, covid-19, portugal, hungary

I would like to travel from Budapest, Hungary to Lisbon, Portugal. I have a return (June 21 - 24, 2020) flight ticket from Budapest, Hungary to Lisbon, Portugal.

For the last 4 months, I was in Budapest, Hungary. I am a non-EU country citizen. I have a residence permit for studying purposes in Hungary.  I could not find information about travel restrictions in Portugal and Hungary for non-EU citizens with (temporary) residence permits.

My question: What are travel restrictions when I will go to Lisbon, Portugal? Should I go to quarantine? What about when I come back to Budapest, Hungary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What are travel restrictions when I will go to Lisbon, Portugal? Should I go to quarantine?**

Right now, in Portugal there are no quarantine-on-arrival measures in place.

On the [UK GOV page for Portugal](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/portugal/entry-requirements), it says:

> ## Air - Mainland Portugal
>
> You will be subject to health screening on arrival. Your temperature will be checked and if it is high or you show signs of being unwell, you will be referred to the health authorities.

---

> **What about when I come back to Budapest, Hungary?**

The [US embassy in Hungary](https://hu.usembassy.gov/covid-19/) states:

> **General Rule:**
>
> Only Hungarian citizens, permanent resident card holders of the European Economic Area (EU member states, Switzerland, and Norway), and other permanent resident card holders who have close Hungarian relatives are able to enter the country, all subject to a 14-day quarantine.

You currently don't fit any of those requirements, therefore you need to apply in Hungarian for an entry permit on the [National Police website](https://ugyintezes.police.hu/uj-ugy-inditasa).